# Proving formula for $\sin(\alpha + \beta)$ with unit circle without making assumptions on $\alpha, \beta$.

Tags: trigonometry, proof-explanation

**Background**

I'm looking over this unit circle proof for the formula for $\sin(\alpha + \beta)$ found on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_identities

The proof is simple enough, but I'm wondering if the proof holds for, let's say $\alpha \in (0, \frac\pi2), \ \beta = \pi$.

This would make the lines $OP, \ OQ$ colinear, and we wouldn't get all those right triangles to work with, which the proof is heavily dependent on.

**Question**

Is there a simple re-write of this proof that deals with this special case?

Comment: If you draw the diagram for $\beta=\pi$, isn't it clear (by some congruent triangles argument) that the same identities hold? $$\sin(\alpha+\beta)=-\sin\alpha\\\cos(\alpha+\beta)=-\cos\alpha$$

Comment: Well, you could just  "deal with this special case".  $\sin (a + \pi) = -\sin a= (-1)\sin a + 0\cos a = \sin a\cos \pi + \sin \pi \cos a$.

Comment: Frequently a proof will state "It suffices to assume ...." because the other cases are straightforward or obvious or will follow directly.  Via the identities $\cos(a +\frac \pi 2)=-\sin a;\sin(a+\frac \pi 2)= \cos a; \cos \frac pi 2= 0; \sin \frac \pi 2 =1$ it suffices to prove for $a,b \in (0, \frac \pi 2)$.  All other cases will follow directly from that result and the identities.

Comment: It's enough to prove it for $\alpha+\beta \le \pi$ as we can apply redaction formulas for all other values

Comment: @JohnDoe - Perfect. Of course, it's even easier to show that adding $\pi$ to any angle preserves the magnitude of the sine and cosine values, but flips the sign.